# Select form not sending selected value from dropdown

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel. I have a simple form that should retrieve a list from the database (which it does correctly) and list them in a dropdown, where I can then choose a specific item from the list and send it to another page.

This is the form:

```
<form name="get-user-by-id" id="get-user-by-id" method="post" action="{{url('do-get-address')}}">
  @csrf
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Users</label>
    <select name "id" class="form-control">
      @foreach($users as $user)
        <option value="{{$user->id}}">{{$user->id}} - {{$user->name}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Link to screenshot as I can't post images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4LEA.png

I pass the "Users" table from MySQL, send it to the form, the form displays all my users, and I want to select one and send it to a page that needs the ID to retrieve the address for the user from a different table.

However, it simply does not send the chosen user.

I've commented out most of my controller to the point where it only displays the request object, and it only shows the CSRF token.

Comment: You have a typo. `<select name "id"` - You're missing the `=`. It should be `name="id"` or the select won't have a name and won't be sent along when submitting the form.

Comment: Please share more details, like the generated markup and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Thank you Magnus, this is the correct answer. I hate forms.

Comment: In my case, I was forgetting to add the name altogether.  Doh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was  `<select name "id"` should have been  `<select name = "id"`

Thank you Magnus Eriksson